# Unable to delete orphaned bucket policy of already-deleted bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cdk

I played around with cdk a while back while [this bug](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/6548) was in effect. I created a stack with a bucket in it and I attached a policy to the bucket. Somehow I ended up in an inconsistent state in which:

1. The bucket shows as deleted
2. The bucket is not actually deleted because if I try to create another bucket with that name it tells me that a bucket with that name already exists
3. There is a policy attached to that bucket which cannot be deleted (this shows up as an error whenever I attempt to delete the stack)
4. The stack cannot be deleted because the bucket policy still has ties to it

Any thoughts on how to remedy this?

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: When you try to manually re-create the bucket, are you doing this in the same AWS account and region that contained the original bucket? You should be able to do that for a certain period of time (4-6 hours) with no issues. You won't be able to create it in a different region or different account, however, until that time passes.